# VB.Net, Could not catch exception in controls Invoke function

Tags: vb.net, listview, async-await, anonymous-function

below function is working fine, get folders list (checked listviewitems) in listview control then load images into thumbnail control, i'm using CancellationTokenSource for cancel the process

```
`     Public Shared Async Function LoadFilesFromLSVAsync(_lsi As ImageListView, _lsv As ListView) As Task(Of Boolean)
        CTS = New CancellationTokenSource
        CT = CTS.Token

        Dim _lamlsi = Async Function()
                     Try
                        For Each _fldr In _lstFolderPath
                          If CT.IsCancellationRequested Then Throw New Exception("user cancelled the process")
                          If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(_fldr) Then
                           For Each _file In _getfiles

                          '---> want to catch this Exception and show to User in msgbox
                                  If CT.IsCancellationRequested Then Throw New Exception("user cancelled the process")

                                  _cnt% += 1
                              Next
                          End If
                        Next
                    Catch ex As Exception
                       Utility.StatusUpdate.TexUpdate.UpdateText(_lblStatus, $"error : {Err.Description }")
                       Throw '---> THROW IS NOT THROW THE EXCEPTION 
                    Finally
                    End Try
                    Return True
                  End Function

        Return Await Task.Run(Async Function()
                          If _lsi.InvokeRequired Then
                               _lsi.Invoke(Async Function() Await _lamlsi())
                           Else
                               Await _lamlsi()
                           End If
                           Return True
                        End Function, CT)
End Function
```

cancel the process

```
 `  Private Sub btnCancelTask_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancelTask.Click
      If Not IsNothing(CTS) Then
        CTS.Cancel()
        CTS.Dispose()
        CTS = Nothing
       End If
    End Sub
```

i want to show "User Cancelled the Process" message box to the user after cancel button clicked but after cancel button clicked process is stopped but i could not get the 'User Cancelled the Process' exception.

Comment: I think you should simplify your code and zoom on your issue if you want to get an answer quickly. It hard for us to read and undestand all your code to provide an answer.

Comment: sorry, i already simplified code before posted.and no issues in code i want to catch the exception if user click the cancel button, i will try again to simplify the lengthy code .. thanks

Comment: @ThomasCarlton, +1 simplified codes.

Comment: If you don't obtain the function result then you also can't see the exception.